# Prevent KeyEvent - Keycode Enter

Tags: android

I have an physical keyboard connected to my android device. I have an application with two buttons and the following two functions handle the KeyEvent:

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(state==State.INI){
        char unicodeChar = (char)event.getUnicodeChar();
        Log.d("CHAR", "UP: "+Character.toString(unicodeChar)+" - "+Integer.toString(keyCode));
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(state==State.INI){
        char unicodeChar = (char)event.getUnicodeChar();
        Log.d("CHAR", "DOWN: "+Character.toString(unicodeChar)+" - "+Integer.toString(keyCode));
    }
    return true;
}
```

but even it handle the ENTER key doesn't prevent it to be handled by the system :s Per example, i changed the return true to false and i can navigate with the arrow keys between the buttons so with return true it is working for almost every key except ENTER :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved with:

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        Log.d("CHAR","YOU CLICKED ENTER KEY");
            return false;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(e);
};
```